# Popup Window like Go SMS Pro received message

Tags: android, popup

I want to create a popup window like the received SMS notification in Go SMS Pro (on top of all activities and also clickable).
I've been making several tries with Popup Windows, but nothing seems to work. Somehow I can't control when the click is done to that "popup window".

Thank you in advance.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                800, 800,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View my, MotionEvent event) {
        testeDisplay();
        return false;
    }
});
wm.addView(myView, params);
```

Comment: Can you add some code you tried? Maybe tell what was wrong with the code exactly.

Comment: Edited with code. I also like to refer that the popup Window has to be displayed in front of all applications,even if you are playing a full screen game.

Comment: instead of using the window manager, have you tried using a custom class that extends Dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use an acitvity as a dialog... Apply dialog theme to your activity.

```
<style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/filled_box</item>
</style>

 <activity android:name=".app.CustomDialogActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_custom_dialog"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomDialog">
    </activity>
```